# Using Styled Components and passing props to psedo element before not working

Tags: css, styled-components

I have the follwing styled component, I am trying to pass a prop to it and use it in a pseudo element selector, in this case `before`. However, it does not work as expected.

However, if I pass the same prop to the background css property or any other property, it works completely fine

Is the following allowed when using styled components?

```js
const Label = styled.label`
  /* This did not work */
  &::before {
    content: ${(props) => (props.field ? "Hi" : "")};
  }
  /*But this works perfectly fine*/
  background: ${(props) => (props.field ? "palevioletred" : "white")};
`;

const Input = styled.input`
  height: 32px;
`;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check devtools, you'll see that your CSS rule is making it to the DOM, but it's an invalid value for the `content` property. It's raw text, with no quotes: `Hi`. It needs to be `"Hi"`.

Try doing (notice the backticks for a new template string literal):

```
content: ${(props) => (props.field ? `"Hi"` : "")};
```